# Routing and form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I have a controller for a resource, BuddiesController. My routes config file up until now has been

```
resources :buddies
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

I didn't realize what the ' resources :buddies ' line was doing until I read up on routing in Rails just now, because the behavior has been identical with what I expected until now. The problem was that I wanted to add a non-CRUD action to the controller: 'search'. Every time I used link_to(:action => 'search'), I would get an exception saying that action 'show' could not be found despite the url being ' localhost:3000/buddies/search ' as expected. I have several questions arising from this:

Firstly, the form I used in 'new' stopped working:

```
%= form_for(@buddy, {:action => :create, :method => :post, :html => {:role => "form"}}) do |f| %>
```

because buddies_path couldn't be found. How could I manually add a buddies_path to my routes?

Secondly, I revised the form to use:

```
<%= form_for(@buddy, :url => {:action => :create, :id => @buddy.id}, :html => {:role => "form", :id => @buddy.id}) do |f| %>
```

but this has caused the form to give me password and email confirmation not matching errors even if they match. What's going on here?

Lastly, what is the best way to add a search action to my resource?

Answer (score 0):

#routes.rb

resources :buddies
    collection do
      get :search
    end
 end

now when you run `rake routes | grep 'buddies'` you will get output something like this :

[image]

now you need to define this search action in your buddies controller . 
 #buddies_controller.rb 
Class BuddiesController < ApplicationController 
  def search 
  end
end

Have your search form in app/views/buddies/search.html.erb

Now in order to open your search form / to hit your search action  you need to use

```
<%= link_to 'Search XYZ', search_buddies_path %>
```

against `buddies#search` you can see `search_buddies`

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb:

```
resources :buddies do
  collection do
    post :search
  end
end
```

This might make your routing works.